# getimagesize hangs indefinitely

Tags: php, php-5.5, getimagesize

The server I am on was recently upgraded, and PHP went from 5.2 to 5.5. I have a script that uses `getimagesize()`, and it worked fine on 5.2, but now the functions hangs indefinitely on the 5.5.  I get no error codes, no return value of `false`, and no return value at all. Based on some of the other posts around, I checked some "standard" things:

- allow_url_fopen is set to 'on' in the php environment
- I am using absolute filepaths beginning with `https://` and ending in `.png`
- the files exist
- even with `ini_set('display_errors', 1)` and `error_reporting(E_ALL)`, no error messages are displayed

I have tried testing the function using Chrome, Firefox, and CLI, but nothing works. Is there anything else I can check?

Comment: What happens when you try with the server filepath?

Comment: wow, i actually get information returned! why is it that the server filepath works but the url doesn't, even when my images are in the same folder as my script?

Comment: Ah. Good. Glad that worked for you. I had a hunch it probably would be just that (seemingly innocuous) thing, when I read your question above. I think a good rule of thumb is: whenever using filepaths with php functions, prefer absolute to relative filepaths - and if you choose absolute, ensure it's the absolute *server* filepath. (See my answer below...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using absolute filepaths with the `getimagesize()` function, ensure that the absolute filepath is the absolute *server* filepath, not just the domain, TLD and filepath as displayed in the browser URI bar.

The same applies to using absolute filepaths with:

`include`

`scandir()`

`rmdir()`

`unlink()`

and many other PHP functions.

Comment: As far as I can see, there is nothing in the PHP documentation that would indicate the type of filepath required. Why would a function like this work with a URI in an older version of PHP?

Comment: The only thing I can think of - and this is me speculating, rather than giving an authoritative answer - is that earlier versions of PHP had less formal requirements (ie. the function worked with either type of filepath) - and those requirements were later tightened up.